# Convert a custom Datetime value to Unixtime format in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm a newbie in Python and my request here is quite straightforward. I want to convert a custom datetime value into Unixtime format in Python 2.7

My values are of the format
26-JUL-17 10.01.34.100000000 AM

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Any code for you date conversion? Feel free to paste your code

Comment: Convert this string to a datetime object then you can convert it easily

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong and if you want to convert the timestamp into date-time then  here is the example code

```
import datetime
import time
current_date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(current_date_time)
```

this will give output like

> 2017-07-26 20:26:35

now you can do formatting on a string to get it formatted in the way you want